# JAVA : Divide 2 bigdecimals and retain maximum number of digits after the decimal point

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to divide 2 big decimals and retain maximum possible number of digits(say 1000 digits) in the non-terminating division result. What code shall I write to do this ?

Please note : Is it possible to have a high accuracy implementation as I am dealing with important data .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an overloaded `divide` method of [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) that takes a `scale` as an argument; you can get an arbitary scale that way.

```
divide(BigDecimal divisor, int scale, RoundingMode roundingMode)
```

Comment: What I mean is , what rounding mode must I use . And what scale will work best ? I tried to play around on divide methods but quite sometimes I got a out of heap limit exceeded error.

Comment: @Nikunj Banka: I'm not going to write your code for you.  Please attempt to at least write your own code; I've already given you the method to use.  The parameters you decide to pass are up to you.

Comment: Rounding mode will turn the decimal into an integer and I want to retain digits after the dicimal. Please help.

Comment: @NikunjBanka No, RoundingMode will not turn the result into an integer, it tells the operation how to round the last digit if the result has more digits than the scale. Did you try anything? Such as result = num1.divide(num2, 1000, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)?

Comment: Yeah, now I completely understand about rounding mode.